# Is there a way to print errors from the JS lint script at the bottom of the script's output?

Tags: eslint, tslint

For instance, I'd like to have the 1 error printed after this log in the console, instead of having to scroll through all the warnings to spot it.

[Output log of npm run lint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrSii.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run eslint with the `—-quiet` flag and it will only output errors